Images stored in Oracle object storage bucket to be shown in oracle Analytics Dashboard (oracle analytics cloud)
I have 10  employee images stored in Oracle object storage bucket. How can we show the images of these employees based on there employee id in the oracle Analytics Dashboard (oracle analytics cloud).
Each image we have separate url from the storage and we have kept the URL access public
We tried storing the image in DB as BLOB . But while creating dataset in OAC dashboard the BLOB column is not visible .

you can use the image plugin available for Oracle Analytics.
Please check the Oracle Analytics Community website to download it.
